# React - Passing a value from child component to the parent component

Tags: reactjs

Using Hooks, how can I pass the **item.id** from the child component to the parent component by clicking the button inside the child component?

***The parent component:***

```
import React from 'react'
import MyList from '../MyList'

const App = props => {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <MyList />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

***The child component:***

```
import React from 'react'
import jsonResponse from '../data'

function MyList (props) {
  const list = jsonResponse.map((item) => {
    return (
      <li className='list-container' key={item.id}>
        <h4>Name: {item.name}</h4>    
        <button className='btn'>More details</button>
      </li>
    )
  })

  return (
    <ul id='container'>
      {list}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default MyList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is all about data flowing down in the components tree. If you want your `Child` to be able to show and/or modify a shared state between `Child` and `Parent` you should [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and pass it down via `props` to it's `children`

```
const Parent = () =>{
    const [title, settitle] = useState('foo')

    return <Child title={title} setTitle={setTitle} />
}


const Child = ({ title, setTitle}) =>{
     return <input value={title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
}
```

In class based components

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    state = { title: '' }

    setTitle = title => this.setState({ title })

    render(){
        const { title } = this.state
        return <Child title={title} setTitle={this.setTitle} />
    }
}


class Child extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const { title, setTitle } = this.props
        return <input value={value} setTitle={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
    }
}
```

But if you really insists that your `Child` holds the `state` (anti pattern) you can do something like this

```
const Parent = () =>{
    const [childProp, setChildProp] = useState(null)

    return <Child setChildProp={setChildProp} />
}

const Child = ({ setChildProp }) =>{
    return <button onClick={() => setChildProp('foo')}>Change to foo</button>
}
```